# Is everything in the Naive Set Theory included in the Axiomatic Set Theory?

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to understand if Naive Set Theory (**NST**) should be understood as a "core" for Axiomatic Set Theory (**AST**).

Is everything (all data) included in NST included in AST?
*Would NST be the "software core" of AST?*

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Naive Set Theory?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/what-is-naive-set-theory)

Comment: How about you give the possible duplicate a read, and if it doesn't answer your quesitons or point you in the direction, let us know.

Comment: It does not answer my question but currently I recognize no way of editing my question; perhaps I should just avoid that "software core" comparison. Thank you.

Comment: The answer to "everything" is a trivial no. Naive set theory is informal, and while its intuitions motivate axiomatic theories none of them can capture them all. For one thing, intuitions are incoherent, so one has to choose what to capture, and informal theories mix base level and meta level arguments, while axiomatic theories can not do that. As for the "core", what that is is too vague and subjective to say anything cogent.

Comment: While I won't downvote, your rollback, IMNSHO, justifies the other closevote which attacks the clarity. As a someone finishing my master's in CS, I'm certainly am interested in your metaphor of "software core". I haven't come across that in any of my studies. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything, it’s probably the other way around. Axiomatic set theory posits some very specific set existence principles, whereas the Comprehension schemata of Naive set theory form a larger range of sets using more general notions of predicate definitions.

It might be useful to think of AST as defining a minimal base set of objects satisfying “pure” set theory, and Naive set theory as patching Set theory to define sets within natural language operating conditions.

This patch doesn’t always work as expected, and sometimes unless you weaken your background operating logic the patch breaks the system.

Comment: Fascinating +1. Do you have any references that might introduce me to your definition of "pure set theory"?

Comment: Thanks @JD, Philip Welch has some great notes online (https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mapdw/current-axiomatic-set-theory.pdf) - AST (particularly theories of the form ZFC + Φ) gives us a formal framework to discuss theories of the set- theoretic hierarchy V, in contrast with Descriptive set theory whose main aim is to consider sets of particular mathematical interest  (eg. the Reals, analytical functions etc). The intuition behind V is a compositional hierarchy of sets extending the Empty set as the main starting point - a minimal definition of an interesting basic collection of sets.

Comment: Awesome! I wanted to compliment your use of the phrase "more general notions of predicate definitions" because it hadn't occurred to me that one might actually use FOPC to provide a rigorous analysis between the essence of more and less formal predications of set theory. That's thought provoking. Time to move you up the ladder.

Comment: I think Alan Weir made an interesting observation that our naive concept of Set is basically the same thing as a Natural Kind or the Extension of a concept - so really, that’s *exactly* what FOPC was made to do!

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

The relationship between naive and formal set theory is one primarily concerned with [foundationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundationalism). How do you know that the set theory you're doing is [logically consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency)? In fact, [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) exposed naive set theory as being inconsistent. Uh oh. To deal with that consistency, set theoreticians began devising rules so that the paradox could be avoided. This led to the infamous [ZF(C) axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) of formal theory (note objection below and see [MathOverflowSE: Can we prove set theory is consistent?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22635/can-we-prove-set-theory-is-consistent/24919#24919)).

**Long Answer**

> Wir müssen wissen.
> Wir werden wissen.
>
> (We must know.
> We will know.)
>
> — [David Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hilbert)

When one does naive set theory, one says a set is a collection of objects. Some objects fit in others. But are there any circumstances that this causes problems in reasoning? The answer is a definitive answer. If one asks, "can I put the collection in itself", one goes down a road and arrives at Russell's paradox. It turns out that if you define a set to exclude itself, you have a problem. Formally:

> R:={x:x∉x} → (R∈R ⇔ R∉R)

which says that if you define a set such that it contains all things that don't contain themselves, then if you consider whether or not the set is a member of itself, it creates the contradiction. Suddenly, mathematicians realized they needed to start figuring out what logical presumptions it takes to avoid these sticky-wickets.

If you want to use a computer metaphor, think of a functional API called APISets. Let's say APISets has a function call called DefineMember() and you make a call:

> DefineMember(R,x='red')

Now, no problems, right?

> R.Contains('red apple') ⇒ T
> R.Contains('human blood') ⇒ T
> R.Contains('blue paint') ⇒ F

But what happens when you do this?

> DefineMember(R,'x∉x') // Note this is a recursive definition!!! Oh, boy.

What is the result of this call?

> R.Contains(R)

Uh, oh. Problems. So, to avoid problems, the method of DefineMember must have exclusions and other rules when interacting with related data and methods. These are what the axioms are.

**See Also**

[PhilSE: What is Naive Set Theory?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/what-is-naive-set-theory)
[PhileSE: Is a set containing itself already a paradox?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55190/is-a-set-containing-itself-already-a-paradox?rq=1)

Comment: Not a very good answer, since we can't prove ZFC is consistent without assuming the consistency of even stronger systems.

Comment: @user4894 Not a very good criticism: 1) Nowhere did I assert that (you did actually read the post, right?) 2) If he doesn't know the difference between naive and formal models, how in Zeus' name am I supposed to explain metalanguages, model theory, and Goedelian objections? (You understand he is a beginner, right?). Questions, comments, and feedback always welcomed! ; )

Comment: I think I see where you read an implication not present. I'll clarify.

Comment: Also put in a link to a MathOverflow article I scanned. He shouldn't have problems getting into turnstiles now, right? :D Feel free to tweak my language if you find my clarification misses the mark. I'd rather have a good answer than hoard credit for contributions.

Comment: @user4894 Better yet, why not provide a good answer so I can learn from your interpretation? I'm here to learn, after all! :D

Comment: Yes, I read the post. And after YOU read your own post, you fixed the error you'd made. So why the snark? A thank you would have been more appropriate if your ego didn't get in the way.

Comment: @user4894 I didn't fix an error. I merely pointed out that you drew an unwarranted implication and helped you through it. I, of course, am appreciative that my improvements will prevent that mistake from being repeated. You are still welcome to respond to my actual criticisms.

Comment: Or provide an answer, if you are interested and capable of course.

Comment: Oh the snark. I'm in awe of your snarkitude. I'm clearly more capable than you my snarky but ignorant friend. You made a mistake and I point it out and *you edited your post to correct your mistake*. Why then the defensive snark? Say thank you and move on. You're welcome.

Comment: @user4894 Sure. You win! lol

Comment: Well just help me out and explain it to me. You misspoke yourself. I noted the issue. *You fixed the problem*. And now you want to throw insults. I truly don't follow your point. Maybe you can explain it. Are you just embarrassed to have made a minor error? Why? Nobody's ego is *that* fragile around here, is it?

Comment: @user4894 One of has been triggered, but I think you keep presuming it's me. My claim was rational and even-minded. I genuinely believe that the conclusion I made an error is a bad conclusion, but you're the one that thumping your chest declaring "you're more capable than me" and that I'm "ignorant". Nowhere did I insult you. I merely claimed that your claim that I made some sort of error itself was an error. In argumentation, it's called shifting the burden of proof. You said I made a mistake, I checked and concluded I hadn't, but modified because I am open to improvement...

Comment: then I shifted the burden to you to explain how I made a mistake. You projected snark onto my words that wasn't there, thumped your chest, and declared yourself the winner because I changed my text. Perhaps I logically made a mistake in my original text, but making a logic mistake isn't the same as crafting statements that are misleading to readers because of the tendency of readers to make errors in inference. So, the standing question has nothing to do with snark nor superiority as you seem to be interested in arguing, but whether your original charge that I made a logic error is correct...

Comment: now, my recollection is that I read the text you criticized and understood why you erroneously thought there was a logic error and improved my text so that the same wrong conclusion couldn't be drawn, something I myself appreciate when others do for me, but after shifting the burden for to explain why your conclusion was in good form and mine was bad, you simply took things personal, no? That's what really interests me about this medium. If we had been at a table communicating, you wouldn't have been triggered by reading snark that wasn't there. Ironically, I don't even recall the actual error

Comment: After Thanksgiving, I'll sit down and review the original claims, the subsequent emendment, and decide if I believe I, you, or both of us were wrong (the third case being equally likely). I have often politely corrected people to find myself being corrected, and have developed the capacity to admit my error. In the event that your correction is itself subject to correction, are you yourself capable? :D For the record, I would prefer to be wrong and have egg on my face.